# Render something on specific page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

So I got this base.vue layout, I am having here my top nav and rest of content, I am wondering if it's possible I add input type search in the sticky div and render it only on specific route pages? For e.g I dont want to have the search bar on every page, but only to appear when I got onto a view with users, where I can filter them.

```
  .sticky.top-0.h-14.bg-white-200.shadow.px-8.flex.items-center
      input(type="search" placeholder="search)
    .container.max-w-full.mx-auto.p-8
      router-view
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script add a computed property that checks if the current route path is `/users` :

```
computed:{
   isUsersPath(){
    return  this.$route.path==='/users'
  }
}
```

then use it in template like :

```
 div(v-if="isUsersPath").sticky.top-0.h-14.bg-white-200.shadow.px-8.flex.items-center
      input(type="search" placeholder="search)
    .container.max-w-full.mx-auto.p-8
      router-view
```